# Unable to capture numbers with regex

Tags: regex

I have the following string:

`car_0001_grp10|banana`

and I would like to isolate the `grp10` section. So I am using the following regex:

```
[grp]+[0-999]+[^|]
```

and this works for `grp10`, `grp56`, `grp999` etc.

But not for `grp1` to `grp9`. How can I include those as well?

Comment: Remove `[^|]`, you do not need that. It also requires one more character to consume.  Use `grp[0-9]+`

Comment: You can just use: `grp[0-9]+` and `[grp]+` is not correct anyway

Comment: In which ways can that string change? Without any more info, you could just do a substring...

Comment: Your current regex would match `ppprrggg10q` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `[grp]+[0-999]+[^|]` matches 1 or more characters `g`, `r` or `p`, then 1 or more digits, and then 1 obligatory char other than `|`.

You need

```
grp[0-9]+
```

or to only grab 1 to 3 digits:

```
grp[0-9]{1,3}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UpifjK/1)

- `grp`  - matches a sequence of characters `grp`
- `[0-9]+`  - 1 or more digits (`[0-9]{1,3}` will match 1, 2 or 3 digits, `000` to `999`).

Comment: If you have any doubts please feel free to drop a comment.

Answer (score 1):

What if you simply do this?

```
grp\d+
```

In which ways can that string change? Do you need to perform any type of validation over it? Only if you need to I would add more complexity to it.

Comment: Thanks! Your solution also works. I just need detection, no validation. I am tempted to accept the answer above as the correct answer, though. I hope that is ok.

Comment: It's up to you, and it depends on how much that input string may vary. But in any case, you can use `\d` instead of `[0-9]` as they are exactly the same. Are there other similar syntaxes to match as well?

Comment: Thanks. No other similar syntaxes, it is the variation of the example string all the time. Things like `truck_0532_grp5|apple`, `boat_0744_grp671|melon`. And thanks for the `\d` tip.

Comment: Are you sure it would never have "grp" anywhere else? Like `grprixcar_123_grp02|lemon`? However in that case it would still work fine, but it would be a close call. ;)

Comment: :) Should be fine for now. Thanks.